# How to construct concrete type from generic function type using typeof in typescript?

Tags: typescript

A lib I'm using exports a function with generic types, but not the type itself, something like this,

```
// some-lib/index.d.ts
export function libFunction<T>(): InternalLibType<T>;
```

I'd like to declare a variable of type

```
const foo: InternalLibType<"something">;
```

I'm trying to construct the desired type for `foo` using `ReturnType<typeof libFunction>` as a starting point, but don't really know how to continue from here.

How can I create a concrete type from the generic type? To be clear, the lib does not export `InternalLibType`.

The library in question is [`use-debounce`](https://github.com/xnimorz/use-debounce). While it does technically export the type from one of its files, the exported type is [not in a file declared in the `exports` field](https://github.com/xnimorz/use-debounce/blob/4d256403c797dc877df788010df24529645ba699/package.json#L8), thus causing errors with some tools that respect the [`exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_exports) field.

Answer (score 2):

This line `export function libFunction<T>(): InternalLibType<T>;` means that `libFunction` expects explicit generic during the call (which is, AFAIK, unsafe in most cases).

This is not a constructor type which expects a generic argument. It means that you are not allowed to use `ReturnType<typeof libFunction<'something'>>`.

If you want to infer return type of this function, you have two options:

**First**, call this function:

```js
const result = libFunction<'something'>();

type Foo = typeof result;
```

**Second**, just use `InternalLibType<"something">`.

SInce TS has a structural type system, type `Foo` is equal to `InternalLibType<"something">`

Comment: The second options would be ideal, unfortunately, `InternalLibType` is not exported

Comment: Could you please provide me with a link to third party library? SOme times it is possible to obtain this type from the other one

Comment: Added more details in the original post to provide more context than I can with a comment.

Comment: @aryzing could you please provide me with exact name of the type or function you want to use

Comment: [`DebouncedState<T>`](https://github.com/xnimorz/use-debounce/blob/master/src/useDebouncedCallback.ts#L22)

Comment: Seems to be that you should create a PR and export this type. I don' see how it can be used without calling the function.

Comment: *"(which is, AFAIK, unsafe)."* That depends what `InternalLibType` is. There is nothing unsafe e.g. about `function foo<T>(): Array<T> { return []; }`.

Comment: @kaya3 you have provided only one valid case for using explicit generic which is not binded to function argument

Comment: ...yes, I provided an example. That's what "e.g." means.

Comment: @kaya3 I know what `e.g` means, just was not clear enough when I wrote `unsafe`. It is updated now. Thank you for pointing this out